# Cannot pass initial data to a formset

Tags: django, formset

In my Django app i have the following:

form:

```
class GameForm(forms.ModelForm):  

    class Meta:
        model = Game

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GameForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        curr_tournament = Tournament.objects.get(id=self.instance.tournament.id)
        self.queryset = Game.objects.filter(tournament=curr_tournament)
        self.fields['opponent_black'].queryset = curr_tournament.participants
        self.fields['opponent_white'].queryset = curr_tournament.participants
```

in views.py:

```
    GameFormSet = formset_factory(GameForm)
```

later then:

```
games = Game.objects.filter(tournament=tournament_id).order_by('number_of_game_in_tour', 'number_of_tour')
gameformset = GameFormSet(initial=list(games.values()))
```

Finally i'm passing `gameformset` into template and rendering it like that:

```
<form>
{{ gameformset.management_form }}
{% for gameform in gameformset %}
    {{ gameform }}
{% endfor %}
</form>
```

This all leads to an error:

```
'auto_id' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

I cannot see the reason why this can happen? Maybe you do?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're doing this. If you want to edit a queryset of values, why don't you use a ModelFormset?

Comment: The reason i don't use ModelFormset is that i need to pass a querysets to opponent_white and opponent_black fields. Maybe you could suggest a way i can do it in "__init__" or "save" methods of my Game class? That would be nice too.

Comment: I don't see how that's got anything to do with it. That queryset allocation is done inside the form, and that wouldn't change with in a ModelFormset.